# How do i run gnu-smalltalk in ubuntu?

Tags: smalltalk

I just downloaded gnu-smalltalk with apt-get on ubuntu. How do i run smalltalk from here?

```
sudo apt-get install -y gnu-smalltalk
```

`gst` gives me the error: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

Comment: Just define your own alias that doesn't conflict with git's alias, for example: `alias gnust={path to your GNU Smalltalk gst program}`. Put that in your login profile.

Comment: You closed a question which is much longer open? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a function, alias, or command named `gst` that is somehow related to Git. Maybe an alias for `git status`?